# Confusion regarding recessional velocity and Lorentz transformation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

Consider that you are receding at a velocity faster than the cosmic speed limit (say, $2c$ with respect to $A$) due to the expansion of our universe. According to me, $A$ is moving at $2c$ and thus for me, it is invisible. Similarly, according to $A$, I am moving at $2c$ and thus for $A$, I am invisible.

Now consider $B$ is moving at velocity $u$ with respect to me in the same direction as me. Thus, it's velocity with respect to $A$ is $2c + u$.

So, if I want to switch the reference frames with $B$ using Lorentz transformation, should I use $u$ as the relative velocity ($v$) in the Lorentz transformation equations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, if I want to switch the reference frames with B using Lorentz transformation, should I use u as the relative velocity (v) in the Lorentz transformation equations?

You cannot use the Lorentz transform in this scenario. The Lorentz transform only applies between inertial frames in flat spacetime. With the cosmological distances involved we must use the FLRW spacetime which has spacetime curvature.